# how to use REGEXP_SUBSTR or INSTR in Oracle SQL to get specific string from a column that varies in character length

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below values stored in a oracle database table: column name=org and am trying to just get the org. user belongs to, in this case: 'abc', 'xyz' i.e., first occurrence after **DC=**. How can i achieve this ?

12~OU=Administrators,DC=abc,DC=enter,DC=msft,DC=com

14~OU=Admin,OU=Users,DC=xyz,DC=enter,DC=msft,DC=com

### output

abc

xyz

I am pretty new to regex_substr, instr expressions.

Any input will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like `regexp_substr(col, '(,|^)DC=([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 1, '', 2)`

The `(,|^)DC=` bit will match either `,DC=` or the start of a line followed by `DC=` (so it won't match another name like `ANOTHERDC=`). The `([^,]*)` bit will match non-comma characters (depending on whether you need to handle escaped delimiters in your field, it's possible you will need to change this). The `(,|$)` at the end of the expression matches either a comma or the end of the line (to ensure we've selected the whole segment... but see below). Setting the 4th parameter to 1 ensures we get the first match. The 6th parameter is set to 2 to specify that we only want to return the part of the match within the second `()`.

Since the matching will be greedy by default, you don't really need to worry about the `(,|$)` bit and could just use `regexp_substr(col, '(,|^)DC=([^,]*)', 1, 1, '', 2)`.  I specified it since I think it's more clear to someone (like me) who doesn't remember whether it defaults to greedy or non-greedy.

Similarly, if you know you don't need to worry about cases where a non-DC name ends with DC, you could just simplify to `regexp_substr(col, 'DC=([^,]*)', 1, 1, '', 1)`.

You could start with something like this and then modify it to suit your requirements.

Comment: Thank you @EdmCoff. I used this `regexp_substr(col, 'DC=([^,]*)', 1, 1, 'i', 1)` to get case-insensitive matchings-to cover `dc=` and `DC=` )

Below 2 expressions returned the same value for OU=Administrators,dc=abc,DC=enter,DC=msft,DC=c.What is the diff? 

`regexp_substr(col, '(,|^)DC=([^,]*)', 1, 1, 'i', 2)`
`regexp_substr(col, 'DC=([^,]*)', 1, 1, 'i', 1)`

could you please help me understand this part of your comment :
The ([^,]*) bit will match non-comma characters (depending on whether you need to handle escaped delimiters in your field, it's possible you will need to change this)

Comment: Those two regular expressions are the same if you don't have other columns that end in dc. If you had the string 'NOTDC=1,DC=2' the first one would return 2, but the second one would return 1 (since NOTDC= contains DC= and it isn't checking for the start of the line or a comma before).

Comment: My comment about the escaped delimiter was about whether you have a way of including commas in your values. I don't know the format of your strings, but I was guessing you might have a way of including commas in the values. e.g. OUT=blah,DC=A\,B,OU=blah might mean "A,B" is the value. If you need to handle something like that, you would need to change the regular expression so it doesn't treat backslash-comma the same as a regular comma. Of course, if you know you can't have a comma character in the value, you don't need to do anything to handle it.